# Azure Databricks - reading tables with koalas

Tags: sql, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-koalas

I am quite new to Databricks, and I am trying to do some basic data exploration with koalas.
When I log into Databricks, under DATA I see 2 main tabs, DATABASE TABLES and DBFS. I managed to read csv files as koalas dataframes (`ksdf=ks.read_csv('/FileStore/tables/countryCodes.csv')`, but I do not know how I could read as koalas dataframe the tables  I see under the DATABASE TABLES. None of those tables have filename extensions, I guess those are SQL tables?
Sorry if my question is too basic, and thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `read_table` function as pointed in the [documentation](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.read_table.html#databricks.koalas.read_table):

```py
ksdf = ks.read_table('my_database.my_table')
```

P.S. It's a part of so called [Metastore API](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/io.html#spark-metastore-table)